# Symfony 3.2 forms: IDs and entity values are mixed up after handle request

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.2

This is an excerpt from my POST data:

```
...
lead[contacts][6][firstName]: test
lead[contacts][6][id]: 543961
lead[contacts][6][lastName]: test
...
lead[contacts][7][firstName]: John
lead[contacts][7][id]: 296310
lead[contacts][7][lastName]: Doe
...
lead[contacts][8][firstName]: foo
lead[contacts][8][id]: 296320
lead[contacts][8][lastName]: bar
...
lead[contacts][9][firstName]: foo
lead[contacts][9][id]: 296330
lead[contacts][9][lastName]: bar
...
```

I see the same post data in Symfony profiler's Request / POST Parameters section. I'm providing the data as text here, because a screenshot would contain lots of other unnecessary information. Due to privacy reasons I replaced the original first and last name values. Yes, "foo bar" appears twice.

My problem is that Symfony mixes up IDs and content after handling the request:

```
    $lead = $this->getRepository()->findWithContacts($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(LeadType::class, $lead);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

screenshot from Symfony profiler's Form / Submitted Data section:

[image: Symfony submit data]

As you can see, test now has John Doe's ID 296310. I have no idea why this is happening. When persisting the form data later, it causes lots of inserts and deletes. I also observed that data was completely lost after processing the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned value in the screenshot is a `LeadContact`, but it looks like you're trying to get a `Lead`. Regardless, you should be passing in the class name of whichever repository you're trying to call.

```
$yourVar = $this->getRepository(YourClass::class)->findMethod($id);
```

I'm guessing you want Lead and not LeadContact like:

```
$lead = $this->getRepository(Lead::class)->findWithContacts($id);
```

Comment: My Lead entity has a OneToMany relation to LeadContact. Therefore, my LeadType contains an embedded form collection "contacts" representing its LeadContact entries.